# Mvvm cross event binding click event not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvmcross

Im having problem binding events in WPF project. So this xaml code is working correctly.

```xml
<Button  mvx:Bi.nd="Command AddNewDeliveryCommand"/>
```

When I changed the binding (below) the method is not invoked.

```xml
<Button  mvx:Bi.nd="Click AddNewDelivery"/>
```

I also installed the MethodBinding plugin casue I thought that was the problem and ensure that the plugin is loaded in LoadPlugins method in setup class but it didnt help.

```cs
public override void LoadPlugins(IMvxPluginManager pluginManager)
{
    base.LoadPlugins(pluginManager);
    pluginManager.EnsurePluginLoaded<MvvmCross.Plugin.MethodBinding.Plugin>();
}
```

ViewModel

```cs
public IMvxCommand AddNewDeliveryCommand => new MvxCommand(AddNewDelivery);
public void AddNewDelivery()
{
  // logic
}
```

Version of framework that im using is .NET 5 and version of the Mvvm Cross is 7.1.2 (latest).

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**
I guess you need to use Command instead of Click in your XAML(not sure why click isn't working)

```
mvx:Bi.nd="Command AddNewDilvery"
```

And you can get rid of Command declaration.

Also ensure you installed that plugin on both core and ui projects.

Comment: Thanks for respons. I tried your solution but it did not help. Maybe Im using incorrect xmlns for binding? I'm using `xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Binding;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf" ` and that's how im using it for button `<Button  mvx:Bi.nd="Click AddNewDelivery"/>`

Comment: I will update my answer with a full demo.

Comment: Yes, this is working but still this is not fixing the issue because for example if I want to bind to different event for example MouseEnter I won't be able to bind method using Mvvm Cross.